# Firefox onLocationChange getting called twice

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have noticed that in our Firefox extension, the listener onLocationChange is getting called twice on facebook.com (something like www.facebook.com/katyperry). Simple sites like google.com do not have this problem. Does anyone have a technique which can filter out the extra onLocationChange event?

Answer (score 0):

See solution here:
https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=16047#p33051

add in:

```
      if (aFlags & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.LOCATION_CHANGE_SAME_DOCUMENT) {
          //Cu.reportError('anchor clicked or javascript simulated anchor click!');
          return;
      }
```